# How can I programatically reset the sign in cookies for a user in G Suite?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-workspace

It's possible to do it manually in the user management UI but I can't find anything in the user management API to do it programatically.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users

Comment: Try [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. You can suspend a user and then immediately restore their account. This has the side effect of invalidating their cookies.

Comment: False, just tested it

Comment: It does work for me. Try putting a delay or suspend in one timed event and unsuspend in another 1 minute later.