# Reset the login cookie by API

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I wonder if there is any way to reset login cookies through the API.
I know there is how to do this through the settings in admin.

Answer (score 2):

Toggling `changePasswordAtNextLogin` flag of a G Suite user logs him out of all devices.

Make the `changePasswordAtNextLogin` value to `True` and then `False` immediately. It is better than suspending the user as incoming mails will not get bounced.

Python example:

```
def changePasswordNextLogin(self,userEmail, status=True): 
    try:
        reqBody = {"changePasswordAtNextLogin":status}
        updateStatus = self.service.users().update(userKey=userEmail,body=reqBody).execute()
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        logging.info("Exception change_passwordNextLogin = %s", e)
        return False

def forceLogoutUser(self, userEmail):
    self.changePasswordNextLogin(userEmail, True)
    self.changePasswordNextLogin(userEmail, False)
    return True
```

Call 'forceLogoutUser(userEmail)' when you want to log a user out of a all devices.

Comment: It would be nice if you added an example or provided a link to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct API for resetting the login cookie. There's a workaround idea from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832631/how-can-i-programatically-reset-the-sign-in-cookies-for-a-user-in-g-suite). For more info, you can also check this [Google thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-apps-manager/Xag_vW8R8ks/f8bwMhL5BQAJ).

Comment: I had seen this post, however, if it suspends the user he stops receiving the email and it is no longer viable for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [G Suite forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/kmW1elUPkuE), the only way to to do this is through a force password reset using [Dito GAM](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager) on the user side.

Related question from SE:

[Is it possible to reset sign-in cookies for all Gmail users in Google Admin?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76109/is-it-possible-to-reset-sign-in-cookies-for-all-gmail-users-in-google-admin)