# G-suite: API for "Reset Sign-In Cookies" for a user

Tags: google-workspace

In G-suite, all sessions for a user can be terminated by the admin using "Reset Sign-In Cookies" option in UI.
Is there a REST API exposed to do the same?
Or any other way to achieve this programatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934817/reset-the-login-cookie-by-api